# I cant get user with USERID (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js

Code:

```
//When I put the function (client.users.get(filas.userid)) didnt works

   db.get(`SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id = ${arg1}`, (err, filas) => {
         var respuesta = new Discord.RichEmbed()
         .setTitle("Respuesta de ticket")
         .setDescription("Tu ticket ha sido respondido!")
         .addField("Staff", message.author.tag)
         .addField("Respuesta", arg2);
         client.users.get(filas.userid).send(respuesta);
       });
```

When i run the bot and execute the command says "Cannot read property "send" of undefinied"

Comment: read the docs on your database module - `filas` is not *one single row* because the query may return many rows of data, you must specify that you want "the first and only" result from the query

Answer (score 0):

It`s can happen because [client.users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) display only chached users. So if you restart bot, this collection can be empty on start and has no users, so you cant get user by id or name.

If this use on message command, and you know this user is on the server, so you can use:

```js
message.guild.members.get(filas.userid)
                        .send(respuesta)
                        .catch(console.error)
```

Or problem in you db request code, check whats your request return with `console.log(filas.userid)`